# TextBox filter using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am struggling to apply a filter on a TexBox. 
I have 3 filter types:

1) `Only Numbers (positive)` 
Example: 123 good,  -123, ad8, 12.0 not good

2) `Only Numbers plus "^" and "." chars`
Example: 123^3, -34, -34.5 good,  ad8, 23-4 not good

3) `Only POSITIVE Numbers plus "^" and "." chars`
Example: 123^3, 34.5 good,  -34, ad8, 23-4 not good

Here is my work:

```
private void PriceInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

            switch (FieldType)
            {
                case InputFieldType.TypeQuantity:
                    tb.Text = KeyFilter.ExtractNumbersOnly(tb.Text);
                    break;
                case InputFieldType.TypePositivePrice:
                    tb.Text = KeyFilter.ExtractPositivePricesOnly(tb.Text);
                    break;
                case InputFieldType.TypePrice:
                    tb.Text = KeyFilter.ExtractPricesOnly(tb.Text);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and KeyFilter:

```
public static string ExtractNumbersOnly(string s)
{
    Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "\\d+");

    return match.Value;
}

public static string ExtractPricesOnly(string s)
{
    Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "^[-]?\\d+([.]\\d+)?$");

    return match.Value;
}

public static string ExtractPositivePricesOnly(string s)
{
    Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "^[+]?\\d+([.]\\d+)?$");

    return match.Value;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to allow for the "^" character in 2/3. Should be: `^(?:[-]?\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)(?:\^[-]?\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)?$` and `^(?:\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)(?:\^[-]?\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)?$` respectively. This allows for things like `-5.5^1.25` and `5.5^-1.25` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

```
^\\d+$
```

(2)

```
^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(\\^)?(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)?$
```

(3) actually easier than (2).  Just take (2) and remove the negative signs.

```
^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(\\^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)?$
```

Comment: I tried ^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(\\^-?(\\.\\d+)?)?$ but now now does not let me to enter 123^4, only 123^ or 123

Comment: @AlexandruCircus I have incorporated your suggestion for (2).  Was designed to NOT take 123^

Answer (score 1):

The required three regex are sequentially(as you asked) at below:

`^\d+$`

`^-?\d+[.^]\d+$`

`^\d+[.^]\d+$`

Please escape the `\` with your escape character in `C#`

Comment: ^-?\\d+[.^]\\d+$ does not find any match when I enter digit. eg:8

Comment: @AlexandruCircus It wasn't in your example. place a `?` after `[.^]`. Which means `[.^]?`

Comment: @AlexandruCircus Sorry, it was. I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.IsMatch("123", "^\\d+$")
Regex.IsMatch("-123^33", "^-?\\d+((\\^\\d+)|(\\.\\d+))?$")
Regex.IsMatch("123^33", "^\\d+((\\^\\d+)|(\\.\\d+))?$")
```

Note that 2nd and 3rd does NOT work if `^` and `.` both are included, e.g. 123.44^2 <- as per given RegEx, this is NOT a correct input