# How to remove invalid entries from a decimal number in wpf text box

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I want to allow the text box to accept only decimal point numbers with maximum 2 digits after decimal point. For example 330.33 is valid and 333.333 is not valid. Text box should restrict all the other special characters. I created two functions one for returning the invalid string and other for comparing the string with characters pressed by user and if the string contains invalid character remove that character. I think this approach of hard coding the invalid chars in a string and comparing it with invalid key stroke is not correct. Is there any better way of doing this?.

```
   private string GetInvalidstring()
   { 
        string invalidCharacterString = @" ! "" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , -  / : ; < = > ? @ A B C D \ | _ ~ ^";
        invalidCharacterString += @" E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ";
        return invalidCharacterString;
   }



    private string CheckValidEntry(string input)
    {
        string invalidCharacters = GetInvalidstring();
        char[] tocheck = input.ToCharArray();
        string copy = input;
        foreach (char c in tocheck )
        {
            if (invalidCharacters.Contains(c))
            {
               // int i = input.IndexOf(c);
                copy = input.Replace(c, ' ');
            }

        }
        return new string(copy.ToList().Where(c => c != ' ' ).ToArray());         

    }
```

Comment: look into `decimal.TryParse()`

Comment: This is achievable using a regex as a filter for your textbox, which prevents invalid characters from ever being entered. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332207/textbox-filter-using-regex

Comment: Op have more stric conditions than TryParse. You think that "333.333" will not be parsed ?

Comment: There are [more countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system) which use a `,` for a decimal marker than a `.`. Don't blindly assume that everybody uses a `.` or when, say, a German user can't use your text box they will be very unhappy.

Comment: Thanks for your information. The application which we are developing is wpf and used only by specific customers. They use only . for decimal marker. Your point will be helpful while developing web based solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to allow only decimal numbers upto two places to decimal

```
^(\d+)?+([\.]{1})?+([\d]{1,2})?$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yT6yR4/2)**

Also take a look at [Restrict a textbox to allow decimal upto two places](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607643/Restrict-a-textbox-to-allow-decimal-upto-two-place)

Comment: Thanks for your information. The code in your link Restrict a textbox to allow decimal upto two places worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
private bool IsValid(string input)
{
    decimal temp;
    return decimal.TryParse(input,out temp) && Math.Round(temp,2)==temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question. I want the function to find and remove the invalid chars entered by users automatically after text box loses focus or prevent the users from typing invalid chars in text box.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Round() function:

```
Math.Round(value, 2);
```

If value is = 333.333333, Math.Round(value,2) return 333.33